# symbolic link without sudo

Tags: node.js, symlink, sudo

I have to run the following command:

```
 ln -s "$(which nodejs)" /usr/bin/node
```

on a computer that I can not use root permissions, there is an alternative? Thanks for help

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez because I used to work at the university, but we do not grant root permissions!

Comment: i'm not sure what do you want to do exactly with node, but install node for you specific user is a good way to avoid permission problems, you can make that using nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm